# Java system.out.println console

Tags: java, system.out

I have code that uses system.out.println to print out an array of string objects. These string objects are then saved to a text file. Everything works great with the program but when the program is compiling the system.out.println prints all of the strings to the console. Is there anyway I can make it so that the user does not see what the system.out.println produces when I save a file?

Comment: use logging such as log4j and use debug/log in place of System.out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all the `System.out.println()` calls and replace them with a call to a logger (for example, [log4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)). Then, you can globally turn on/off logging in your application or set different logging levels using configuration files. In general, it's a bad idea to leave `System.out.println()` calls in production code, that's what loggers are for.

Answer (score 1):

Run your program like this:

```
java Program > /dev/null
```

On Windows, you can do this instead.

```
java Program >NUL
```